# Select rows of a matrix using binary array

Tags: python, numpy

Supposing that I have a matrix with a format (m x n) and one array with dimension (m) containing booleans. I would like to select and extract just the rows of my matrix in which the corresponding index of the m-dimension array contains a true value. There must be a really simple way to solve this issue which I am not aware of.

A minimal reproducible able example that might help to better explain:

```
A = np.array([[ 1,  4,  5, 12],
              [-5,  8,  9,  0],
              [-6,  7, 11, 19],
              [13, 15, 16, 19]])

B = np.array([1,0,1,1])
```

Expected output:

```
Out[1]: 
array([[ 1,  4,  5, 12],
       [-6,  7, 11, 19],
       [13, 15, 16, 19]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast `B` to bool, so the indexing is boolean based:

```
A[B.astype(bool)]

array([[ 1,  4,  5, 12],
       [-6,  7, 11, 19],
       [13, 15, 16, 19]])
```

---

Otherwise, being `B` an array of integers, you'll be performing integer indexing, and will just be indexing on the rows specified by the indices:

```
A[B]

array([[-5,  8,  9,  0],
       [ 1,  4,  5, 12],
       [-5,  8,  9,  0],
       [-5,  8,  9,  0]])
```

Find more on boolean indexing [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing)